# Issue with displaying number of elements based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a question previously to solve my dilemma as to how I would show the amount of elements based on a dropdown value. For example, if I selected "2", 2 div elements would show up. If you select "3", 3 elements would show up.

Currently, my page is set up in a way so that when you select "1", Element 1 shows up. When you select "4" element 4 shows up.

[Example](http://intimate-nutrition.com/upload/)

```
<select class="signupSearchModelTypeSelect" id="selectModelNumber" name="modelsCount" style="display: none;">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<div class="signupLabelSelectContainer modelNumberAll modelNumber1">
blablabla
</div>
<div class="signupLabelSelectContainer modelNumberAll modelNumber2">
blablabla
</div>
<div class="signupLabelSelectContainer modelNumberAll modelNumber3">
blablabla
</div>
<div class="signupLabelSelectContainer modelNumberAll modelNumber4">
blablabla
</div>

.....
$(".signupSearchModelTypeSelect").chosen({
            inherit_select_classes: true,
            disable_search: true
        }).change(function(f, g) {
            if ($(this).attr("name") == "modelsCount") {
                //This section controls the dropdown
                $(".modelNumberAll").addClass("hide");
                $(".modelNumber" + $(this).val()).removeClass("hide")
            }
....
```

[so we built something like this in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/Hk87V/8/)

And I modified my JS to look like this:

```
$(".signupSearchModelTypeSelect").chosen({
    inherit_select_classes: true,
    disable_search: true
}).change(function(f, g) {
    if ($(this).attr("name") == "modelsCount") {

    //This section controls the dropdown
    var number = $(this).val();
    $('.CommonAttribute').hide().slice( 0, number ).show();
});
```

[And the result is that the div's don't change at all now](http://intimate-nutrition.com/upload/index2.html)

What's wrong with this? Thanks!

**Edit:** Updated html to replace `.CommonAttribute` with `.modelNumberAll`.

Comment: What happened to the `:lt()` I gave you two days ago?

Comment: I don't see your javascript in that page...

Comment: That page has a Javascript error in the script which contains the code that is not working. Javascript errors will halt execution of the script in which they occur. Try again after fixing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not actually used the class "CommonAttribute" on the items you want to show/hide. The query for $('.CommonAttribute') has an empty result.

To determine this, I opened Chrome Devtools, set a breakpoint to stop during the change event, changed the value of the select box, then selected the "$('.CommonAttribute')" query in the code editor, right clicked it and chose "Evaluate in Console". It shows an empty result, and indeed the numbered elements do not have this class, as they do in the jsFiddle.

Comment: I am sorry about that! I can't believe I overlooked this - I fixed all of this, yet the result is still the same.